# R rename column with a value from another dataset

Tags: r

I want to rename columns in one dataset based on the values from another dataset, for example...

```
> set.seed(1234)
> questions = data.frame(Area=c("Zone1","Zone2","Zone3"),
                       X1a=sample(10,3), X1b=sample(10,3), X1c=sample(10,3),
                       X1d=sample(10,3), X1e=sample(10,3))
>questions
   Area X1a X1b X1c X1d X1e
1 Zone1   2   7   1   6   3
2 Zone2   6   8   3   7   9
3 Zone3   5   6   6   5  10

answers = data.frame(F1=c("question1","question2","question3","question4","question5"))
 > answers
         F1
1 question1
2 question2
3 question3
4 question4
5 question5
```

Now I want to replace X1a,X1b,etc... with the contents in answers, So I tried using names()

```
> names(questions)[2:6]<-c(answers[1,],answers[2,],answers[3,],answers[4,],answers[5,])
```

But the result I get is...

```
   Area 1 2 3 4  5
1 Zone1 2 7 1 6  3
2 Zone2 6 8 3 7  9
3 Zone3 5 6 6 5 10
```

I seem to get a rownumber instead of the actual contents of the cells, I also get the same result from using...

```
names(questions)[2:6]<-c(answers[1,1],answers[2,1],answers[3,1],answers[4,1],answers[5,1])
```

Is there something simple I´m overlooking here?

Comment: Try `names(questions)[-1] <- as.character(answers$F1)`

Comment: The underlying issue that you're having is that when you create the dataframe `answers`, `F1` gets saved as a `factor` class. `factor`s are saved as numbers that are "labeled" with the values you pass. Thus, when you try to assign the values as names, you just get the numbers instead. You can do exactly what you're already doing by just changing `answers` to `answers = data.frame(F1 = c("question1", "question2", "question3", "question4", "question5"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:  `names(questions) <- c("Area",t(answers))`

You need to convert from factor to string.

(Strangly my in between version: `names(questions) <- t(answers$F1)` worked)

Comment: This code doesn't work. It provides the same output the OP is already getting.

Comment: If you insist on using `t()` then just do `t(answers)` because it converts to character automatically.  But `as.character(answers$F1)` is the standard idiom.

Comment: @RichardScriven: You mean like: c("Area",t(answers$F1)). This is the reason why I was down voted. It doesn't work.

Comment: No.  Drop the `$F1` if you use `t()`.  Do just `c("Area", t(answers))`

Comment: Oh intresting. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, the t(answers) solution worked out great. in my actual data set the answers data was subsetet from a bigger data set depending on input, so I couldn´t use anything that called on the variables names themselves.